# Spring SimpleTriggerContext get proper nextExecutionTime

Tags: java, cron, spring-scheduled

I have job that will run every 10 mins. I don't want to use Spring Scheduler based on last job run next job will schedule to run. Suppose First job ran at 10:15 AM, Subsequent job needs to run at 10:25 AM. When i googled i saw posts with `nextExecutionTime`. When i use `nextExecutionTime` my subsequent job is running at 10:20 instead of 10:25. Below is my code, Can any one give an idea how i can run my job at exact 10 mins from last run.

```
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("0 0/10 * * * ?");
SimpleTriggerContext triggerContext = new SimpleTriggerContext();
triggerContext.update(Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant()), Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant()), Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant()));
Date nextFireAt = trigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
System.out.println(nextFireAt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below. I provide below the sequence.

1. Get the date now.
2. Add 10 mins to the date and get a new updated date
3. Update the like triggerContext.update(null, null, date in which you have added 10 mins);

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I ran my program at 10:09, So next job should execute on 10:19, But it is executing on 10:20.

Comment: What is the time taken by that Job? I mean how much does that job take ?

Comment: Execution time is 20-30 secs

Comment: Ok, then, before starting the actual running of Job, take the date object as Date currentDate = new Date(); then add 10 mins. Hopefully it will solve the problem.

Comment: I updated currentDate to 10 mins it doesn't works
```CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("0 0/10 * * * ?"); impleTriggerContext triggerContext = new SimpleTriggerContext();triggerContext.update(null, null,Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now().plusMinutes(10).toInstant()));Date nextFireAt = trigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext); System.out.println(nextFireAt);```

Comment: Use like this triggerContext.update(null, null,date10Mins); like this and try